# SpringBootServletInitializer#configure is not called for executable WAR

Tags: spring-boot

I want to migrate my war application to Spring boot application.

I follow instruction from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot and I made class

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    application.banner(new MyBanner());
    application.sources(MyEndpoint.class);
    return application;
  }
}
```

I got deployable WAR.

I next phase I want to get executable WAR. I made class

```java
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyInitializer.class, args);
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I call `java -jar target/myapp.war` MyInitializer#configure is not executed

I'm confused a bit. How to avoid copy-paste logic from MyInitializer to MyApplication. Do I have to join these classes into one?

Comment: Did you add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Yes, I use the plugin to create executable WAR

Comment: Which is as excepted. The initializer is only executed when deploying to a servlet container not when executing as an embedded war.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I expected something opposite, so I raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7040

Comment: Still it is as it should work, especially for the `SpringBootServletInitializer` as that basically does the same as the `main` method in a standalone application. It would bootstrap the code again, and again, and again, and again, and again because each time a new application would be started.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I simply thought that executable WAR behaves identically launched standalone or by servlet container

Comment: No it doesn't as those are 2 completly different ways of bootstrapping your application. And the `SpringBootServletInitializer` is the deployable version of the executable `main` method. And only one of them, depending on the way of deployment, will be used. The easiest way is to simpy merge them into one (as seen in the answer).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personnally I merge both together:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return MyApplication.build(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApplication.build(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder build(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.banner(new MyBanner()).sources(MyEndpoint.class);
    }
}
```

- I really don't think `SpringBootServletInitializer` will ever be
  executed when launching your WAR as an executable. Even though the
  file extension is a `WAR`, you are really using it as a `JAR`.
- When lauched from the command line, the *Spring Boot entry point* is the main method and `SpringBootServletInitializer` is just not interpreted as a *Spring Boot entry point*.
- SpringBootServletInitializer is only used when deployed as a WAR: the container would use the `SpringBootServletInitializer` as the *Spring Boot entry point* (and the main method would be completely ignored).